# Upgrading gitlab after upgrade Fedora 30 to Fedora 31

Tags: fedora, upgrade, gitlab

Few mounts ago I upgrade my gitlab server from Fedora 30 to Fedora 31 and faced this issue:

[root@eric yum.repos.d]# yum update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:06 ago on Sun 03 May 2020 01:46:17 PM EEST.
Dependencies resolved.

Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package gitlab-ce-12.6.0-ce.0.el7.x86_64

## - nothing provides policycoreutils-python needed by gitlab-ce-12.10.2-ce.0.el7.x86_64

## Package                        Architecture                Version                                 Repository                      Size

Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 gitlab-ce                      x86_64                      12.10.2-ce.0.el7                        gitlab-ce                      759 M

## Transaction Summary

Skip  1 Package

Nothing to do.
Complete!

In Fedora 31 package is called : policycoreutils-python-utils.noarch : SELinux policy core python utilities

Is there any workaround to fix this problem?